# noscript.innerHTML has different results cross browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, cross-browser

Following code has different results in safari vs chrome vs firefox.

```
var noscript = document.getElementsByTagName('noscript')[0];
console.log(noscript.innerHTML);
```

Result in Chrome:

```
<img alt="***" title="***" src="***" width="***" height="***" srcset="***" sizes="***"  />
```

Result in Firefox:

```
<img alt=\"***\" title=\"***\" src=\"***\" width=\"***\" height=\"***\" srcset=\"***\" sizes=\"***\"  />
```

Result in Safari:

```
&lt;img alt="***" title="***" src="***" sizes="***"  /&gt;
```

How can one create and inject a valid img element cross browser?

Following works in Chrome & Firefox

```
noscript.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',noscript.innerHTML);
```

Following works in safari

```
var html = new DOMParser().parseFromString(noscript.innerHTML, "text/html");
noscript.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',html.documentElement.innerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple client detection and compatibility detection techniques out there to detect the browser and then execute the correct code for each situation.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851769/10905239